# AWS Sagemaker Kernel appears to have died and restarts

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-sagemaker

I am getting a kernel error while trying to retrieve the data from an API that includes 100 pages. The data size is huge but the code runs well when executed on Google Colab or on local machine.

The error I see in a window is-

**Kernel Restarting
The kernel appears to have died. It will restart automatically.**

I am using an ml.m5.xlarge machine with a memory allocation of 1000GB and there are no pre-saved datasets in the instance. Also, the expected data size is around 60 GB split into multiple datasets of 4 GB each.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

I think you could try not to load all the data into memory, or try to switch to a beefier instance type. According to https://aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/pricing/instance-types/ ml.m5.xlarge has 15GB memory.

Jun